# po2html missing html template

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, translate-toolkit

I have no coding experience but I need to convert a .po file into an .html file. I am learning how to use this translate toolkit.

I am using translate tool kit here: http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/translate-toolkit/en/latest/commands/html2po.html

Managed to get far as to install python and things.
I have gotten as far as below, and am unsure how to proceed.

Folder xh has example.po (which has relevant msgids and msgstr) and also example.html (which is blank)

```
C:\Users\bob>po2html -i C:\Users\bob\Desktop\xh -o C:\Users\bob\Desktop\xh
processing 1 files...
po2html: WARNING: Error processing: input C:\Users\Oh\Desktop\xh\example.po, output C:\Users\Oh\Desktop\xh\example.html, template None: must have template file for HTML files
[###########################################] 100%
```

How do I create this html template and what does it look like (My only knowledge is that you can create a HTML file in notepad, but I'm not sure what to put in it so example.html is blank atm)